# NextJS, Prisma and Postgres. How would I link two fields in a model to a single other model

Tags: postgresql, prisma

I've got two models, User and Project. A User will have some typical properties and the Project will contain some fields like title, codename, runtime (this is a media project, like a TV show). My question comes in the form of two fields in the Project model, specifically dubbing_produer and talent_coordinator. I'd like these two fields to be of type USER as they'll be filled from a listing of users in the UI. While I could make these fields type String, the link back to the Project in both database and UI would be a nice benefit. I'm having trouble with Prisma allowing this relationship, it's complaining that I have two fields that link to the same model. The code pasted below, including the Project Project[], Project Project[] don't make sense in this context.

What would be the best way to have multiple fields link back to one model?

```
model User {
  id         Int     @id @default(autoincrement())
  email      String  @unique
  password   String
  first_name String
  last_name  String
  title      String?
  image      String?
  role       String? // view, edit, admin

  Project Project[] <--- ???
  Project Project[] <--- ???
}

model Project {
  id                  Int     @id @default(autoincrement())
  title               String
  codename            String?
  number              String? // 552,236 (Sugar number)
  format              String? // Feature, Series, Special
  content_type        String? // Live-Action, Animation, UN Style, Audio Description
  runtime_in_minutes  Int?
  number_of_episodes  Int?
  dubbing_producer    User?   @relation(fields: [dubbingProducerId], references: [id])
  dubbingProducerId   Int?
  talent_coordinator  User?   @relation(fields: [talentCoordinatorId], references: [id])
  talentCoordinatorId Int?
}
```